# How to make image responsive while calling

Tags: html, image, css, responsive

I have a below HTML code in which the images are **purely responsive.**

```
<div class="flexslider js-fullheight">
        <ul class="slides">
        <li  style="background-image: url(images/slide_1.jpg); width:100%;" border="0" alt="Null">
            <div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center js-fullheight slider-text">
                    <div class="slider-text-inner">
                        <h2>Start Your Startup With This Template</h2>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get started</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style="background-image: url(images/slide_3.jpg);">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center js-fullheight slider-text">
                    <div class="slider-text-inner">
                        <h2>Take Your Business To The Next Level</h2>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get started</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style="background-image: url(images/slide_2.jpg);">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center js-fullheight slider-text">
                    <div class="slider-text-inner">
                        <h2>We Think Different That Others Can't</h2>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get started</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

In this, the `slide_1.jpg` image is responsive. What I want is, I want to replace this image with my actual Image.

I tried changing the image by giving `width:100%` but the Image was still getting stretched. Any idea, how to make that image responsive.

**Update**

and the css is below

```css
#fh5co-hero .flexslider .slider-text > .slider-text-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 700px;
}
#fh5co-hero .flexslider .slider-text > .slider-text-inner h2 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #fh5co-hero .flexslider .slider-text > .slider-text-inner h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
#fh5co-hero .flexslider .slider-text > .slider-text-inner .fh5co-lead {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexslider js-fullheight">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li style="background-image: url(/images/slide_1.jpg);">
                    <div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
                    <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center js-fullheight slider-text">
                    <div class="slider-text-inner">
                    <h2>Start Your Startup With This Template</h2>
                    <!--<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get started</a></p>-->
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                    <li style="background-image: url(images/slide_3.jpg);">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center js-fullheight slider-text">
                                <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                    <h2>Take Your Business To The Next Level</h2>
                                    <!--<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get started</a></p>-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li style="background-image: url(images/slide_2.jpg);">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center js-fullheight slider-text">
                                <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                    <h2>We Think Different That Others Can't</h2>
                                    <!--<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get started</a></p>-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a separate css sheet? You have style="background-image:  Is that in the css page? Do you have '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">'  in the head section on the page?

Comment: @mlegg: background-image is not in separate css page. Also, yes I have viewport in the head section.

Comment: Please include all code necessary to answer the question in the question itself (not on jsfiddle) as a [mcve].

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Updated the fiddle with the relevant css. Let me know if anything else is missing.

Comment: Please read my comment again, especially the part about **(not on jsfiddle)**.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan; Updated the question, is that you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

If you change only the width to 100% it will stretch the image inside of it. Try adding `height:auto;` to the inline CSS in order for the image to scale correctly.

If that doesn't work, try replacing your `background-image` property with:

```
background: url(images/slide_1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: which css do you want, I have added the original html

Comment: **Updated the fiddle, kindly have a look**